# Convert a numeric number to date

Tags: r

[DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HRmz.png)
`as.POSIXct(DADOS1[c(3:n), c(1)], tz = "GMT", origin = "1970-01-01")`

I have a dataset with many columns and I want to convert the first column which is a numeric number to a date. With the command that I am using it is giving an error: "Error in as.POSIXct.default(DADOS1[c(3:n), c(1)], tz = "GMT", origin = "1970-01-01") :
do not know how to convert 'DADOS1[c(3:n), c(1)]' to class “POSIXct”"

Comment: Please post `dput(head(DADOS1[,1:2]))` through edit. Also, why do you want to convert the column beginning with row 3? It's most likely not possible to store the result in the same data frame column.

Comment: I uploaded an image with many values. I do not want to convert the 1 and 2 line because are not numbers.

Comment: Your data is not numeric, it has on the first two rows "header" like info, making the whole column of type character.

Comment: How can I place 3 lines of headers when I read the .csv?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  date = 20230301:20230401
)
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, tz = "GMT", origin = "1970-01-01")
```

I am not sure what DADOS1 is. Could you please include an example data?

Comment: I uploaded an image, if you can check I would appreciate it.